# Use pandas to create multi plot in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using the jupyter notebook to draw a bar chart, and I want to draw a pandas plots in a for loop.

Here is my Dataframe that I want to draw a bar chart in a for loop

```
In[7]: test_df
    Lehi    Boise
1   True    True
2   True    True
3   False   False
4   True    True
5   True    True
6   True    True
7   True    True
8   False   False
```

My code

```
place = ['Lehi','Boise']
for p in place:
    bar = test_df.groupby(p).size().plot(kind='bar')
```

But I only get the 'Boise' bar chart...
If I write them in different jupyter cells, it works well

```
In[9]  bar = test_df.groupby('Lehi').size().plot(kind='bar')

In[10] bar = test_df.groupby('Boise').size().plot(kind='bar')
```

Is there any solution to solve this problem in jupyter notebook.
Thanks!

Comment: please check if all the elements of lehi and boise are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that without extra specification, the loop is overwriting the same plotting axes.  You can more explicitly create a new Axes within the loop for each plot, and map `df.plot` to those Axes:

```
colors = ['red', 'green']
place = ['Lehi','Boise']
for p in place:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
    bar = test_df.groupby(p).size().plot(kind='bar', color=colors, ax=ax)
```

This will create multiple plots under one cell.  I include the `colors` bit b/c there was something like that in your original Q (which was undefined).  I believe the `groupby` operation will always sort `False` first then `True`, so you just have to present the colors in the order you want to match.